# Fitting a model to data for prediction - best choice for data

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, model-selection, model

I have some data I need to fit a model to that can be used for prediction (interpolation). The data is summarized by the plot below. The black line is x=y.

[image]

I want to be able to fit a model so as I can use it to predict any value of the y axis as a function of x axis, as well as get the uncertainty in that estimate.

However in my data, the variance of the y axis variable increases as the x axis variable increases.
In addition, there is another continuous explanatory variable called SequenceSize (plotted as factor to clearly see the colours) which I think I have to take into account, as it is also correlated (negatively) with the variance of the y axis variable, whilst not really affecting the mean so much. As can be seen in the two plots below.

[image]
[image]

So from a model fit to the data I would like to be able to use it to do.

1. Plugin the value of SequenceSize and the x axis variable.
2. Get out an estimate of the y axis variable along with some measure of uncertainty in the y estimate, given how the variance and uncertainty is affected by the x axis variable and by SequenceSize.

However I'm reading the massive R book by Crawley, and I'm having trouble deciding which model would be best to do this. I'm thinking maybe a multiple regression if I linearized the data by taking log of x and y, but I'm unsure if that's right because of how the variance of the data acts.

Thanks,
Ben W.